# Notification When Post Approved

Tags: plugins, posts, notifications

Does anyone know of a notification plugin, snippet that will allow me to when i approve a users post they get a notification show up on the menu, and when they go to the notification page it says something like

"Your post [title with hyperlink to post] has been approved/ hasnt been approved"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`publish_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) action hook for notifying post author.

```
function wpcs_author_notification( $post_id ) {

   $post = get_post( $post_id );
   $author = get_userdata( $post->post_author );

   $message = "Hi " . $author->display_name . ", Your post, " . $post->post_title . " has just been published at " . get_permalink( $post_id );

   wp_mail( $author->user_email, "Your article is published", $message );

}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'wpcs_author_notification' );
```

This function will notify author for published post. You can modify message in above code.

Comment: He was looking for a notification in the dashboard/menu but this should get him started. :)

Comment: Oh. I thought he wanted to send an email. But yes, he can modify the function to add a notification bubble.

Comment: Hello, Thank yo for your help, sadly i dont know how to modify it to add a notification bubble.